# Ranking list with all the users

Tags: php

I have a database (**GAMES**) with userid, name, sports and points.

**user1**, football, 10 points - 
**user1**, Basketball, 5 points

**user2**, footbal, 8 points - 
**user2**, Baketball, 3 points

To get the rank of ***each user by each sports***, I am using the following code which is working perfect:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
sports,
FIND_IN_SET(footbal, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sports 
ORDER BY points DESC) 
FROM ".GAMES." 
)
) AS rank
FROM ".GAMES."
WHERE userid = 1
";
```

**Results**:

**user1** (1) (1 is the rank)

When I use user2 in WHERE I get: **user2** (2)

Now I want a list like this (For more than 1000 users):

1- **User1** (1)

2- **User2** (2)

3- **User15** (44)

3- ....

Any help will be appreciated. I you need more explanation, just ask.

Comment: can you tell me how you want your result?

Comment: Hi Harsh, I want a list of all the users with their rank. Like 1- user1 (1) - user9 (88)...

Comment: Please clarify if you want "dense" or "gapped" ranking or no respect for ties.  If there are 4 users and the "middle middle-ranked" users have the same rank what do you expect?  Ranks: `1, 2, 2, 4`, `1, 2, 3, 4`, or `1, 2, 2, 3`?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$sqls = array();
foreach ($sports as $sport) {
    $sqls[] = "SELECT name FROM ".GAME." WHERE sports='".$sport."' ORDER BY points ASC"
}
```

Then loop through slqs variable to get all the lists.

And finally, to get the parenthesis part, I would do when I will print the list.

Comment: Hi jolmos, thanks for you help. Do I have to add your code to one I already have?

Comment: Hi, yes, I assumed you have your sports stored in an array($sports), then it's depend on how you fetch and print the results

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
"SELECT * FROM GAMES WHERE userid = ".$userid." ORDER BY points DESC"
```

I don't see why you would need to use anything else, as you are just ordering by their points.

or if you also want to specify a sport,

```
"SELECT * FROM GAMES WHERE userid = ".$userid." AND sports = '".$sport"' ORDER BY points DESC"
```

You would need to use an array to loop through each sport then just use the above query again.
e.g.

```
$ranks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GAMES WHERE userid = ".$userid." AND sports = '".$sport"' ORDER BY points DESC", $database);

$count = 1;
while(list($userid, $name, $sport, $points) = mysql_fetch_row($ranks)) {
    //formatting here. table row, paragraph etc or:
    echo "$count - $name ($userid)";

    $count++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott, but you don't get the rank (Position) by each sport.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 1 select like this:

`$sql = 'SELECT * from table_GAMES WHERE points >= 1000 ORDER BY name'`

The result would have all users with more than or equal to 1000 sorted alphabetically. You can then display it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo ' (' . $row['points'] . ')';
}
```

Comment: Hi stubben, you misanderstood my question. 1000 means: If I have a lot of users. It has nothing to do with the points.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not really implement ranking in a convenient way. This is discussed, for example, here: [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

In that thread linked above you can see some solutions you could try, or alternatively you could use some simpler SQL to get an ordered list and use PHP to calculate/count the ranks:

```
// ...
$sql = 'SELECT userid, sports, SUM(points) AS total_points FROM games GROUP BY userid, sports ORDER BY sports, SUM(points) DESC';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$rank = null;
$last_sport = null;
$sports_ranking = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if($row->sports == $last_sport) {
       $rank++;
    } else {
       $rank = 1;
    }
    $sports_ranking[$row->sports][] = array(
        'userid' => $row->userid,
        'rank' => $rank,
        'total_points' => $row->total_points
    );
}

echo('<pre>'); print_r($sports_ranking); echo('</pre>');
// ...
```